# The SECOND resultset is giving error

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g, resultset

I am trying to access the column names of 2 different databases; one is SQL and the other is Oracle. The program compiles fine, but while execution it gives an error for the rsmo(resultset for oracle): stating ResultSet.next was not called.

About the program:

I take the databasenames, ip, userid and pass from a text file and store them in strings before passing it to connection. The aim is to copy data from one database to another, but for now all i am doing is finding the column names and number of columns before insertion. At any point of time, there will only be 2 tables viz one of SQL and the other of oracle, to copy to and from. Hence i have an array of colNames for storing the names of the respective columns.

```
Code snippet:
    Connection CONN_SQL = DriverManager.getConnection(URL_SQL, USER_SQL, PASS_SQL);     
    Connection CONN_ORA = DriverManager.getConnection(URL_ORA, USER_ORA, PASS_ORA);

    DatabaseMetaData dmds = CONN_SQL.getMetaData();
    DatabaseMetaData dmdo = CONN_ORA.getMetaData();

    ResultSet rsms = dmds.getColumns(null, null, SQLTABLENAME, null);
    ResultSet rsmo = dmdo.getColumns(null, null, ORACLETABLENAME, null);
    String rs;
    int columns=1, columno=1;
    while(rsms.next() || rsmo.next()){
    if(rsms!=null){
            colNames[0][columns]=rsms.getString(4);
            System.out.println("colnames:" +colNames[0][columns]);
            columns++;}
    if(rsmo!=null){
        System.out.println(rsmo.getString(1));
        colNames[1][columno] = rsmo.getString(4);
        System.out.println("columno: "+colNames[1][columno]);
        columno++;
    }
    }
```

Things i have tried and their failures:

1. Tried 2 while loops for the 2 result sets, the rsms(SQL one) runs perfectly, returning the column names. But the rsmo(oracle one) does not run. It skips the while loop, but executes any statement before AND after it.
2. I have tried to make another resultset which just executes a SELECT top 20 query for both SQL and oracle. AGAIN, it works properly with SQL but ORACLE's ResultSet is skipped.
3. I have tried some solutions from stackoverflow such as:

   1. Setting resultset to first, which results in a runtime exception stating "Exhausted    ResultSet".
   2. if(!rs.next()), which also results in an Exhausted ResultSet exception.

I just want to know what i am doing wrong, or a solution is always appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:

Found out that the resultset isnt allowed to be iterated more than once. Tried closing the ResultSet of SQL, after use, and then opening the other. Still no use, the Oracle RS is skipped again.

Comment: I hope Oracle has data you are looking for.

Comment: Obviously, it does. I have another program ready and executed which copies from the same table and inserts into oracle. No issues there. But there, i already know the column names. Here, i need to store the column names beforehand. Lastly, I can assure you that Oracle has the data.

Comment: And no problems in connectivity right?

Comment: No problems at all. The driver registers fine, the connections are eshtablished too.

Comment: You short circuit operator is the problem than.

Comment: That may be the case, but as Scary Wombat has pointed out, its a flaw in my logic, which I have seemingly fixed by using 2 different while loops for SQL and oracle. But the 2nd while loop is skipped. Anything before and after the 2nd loop is executed, though.

Comment: In that case there is nothing coming from database it seems.

Comment: @DarshanLila it works fine when i access it from another program or directly from the DB

Comment: Are you still using the same code you posted?

Comment: Yeah. Just trying 2 different loops now. The content is still the same, so are the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

In this code

```
while(rsms.next() || rsmo.next()){
```

if `rsms.next()` is evaluated to true, then `rsmo.next()` will not even be called and may be false.

In you `while` loop, when would `rsms` or `rsmo` suddenly become null?

```
while (true) {
     boolean foundms = false;
     boolean foundmo = false;
     if (rsms.next()) {
         // do stuff
         foundms = true;
     }
     if (rsmo.next()) {
         // do stuff
         foundmo = true;
     }

     if (!foundms && !foundmo) break;
 }
```

If this is still not working, then borrowing try (from Darshan's answer )

```
ResultSet rsmo = dmdo.getColumns(null, null, ORACLETABLENAME, null);
ResultSetMetaData md = rsmo.getMetaData();
for (int i=1; i<=md.getColumnCount(); i++)
{
  System.out.println(md.getColumnName(i));
}
```

Comment: I have tried it the other way too, that is, while(rsmo.next() || rsms.next()), the same exception occurs. Also, you do have a point, but it skips the resultset for oracle, even when i execute it separately. I thank you for pointing out the flaw in my logic. I fill fix it by doing 2 while loops, but the problem still persists!

Comment: First, no they wont suddenly become null. There are like thousands of records in the table. Second, i tried your solution, it skips rsmo.next() and executes only rsms.next()

Comment: If they will not become null then why check?  What do you mean by skips?  As you can see from the code, it must mean that there are not more records.. Are you sure it is not throwing an exception?

Comment: I wasnt checking initially, but it was a desparate move to see what happens, it clearly skipped it. By skip, i mean it doesnt go inside the loop at all. I have tried SOP statments, the ones before and after the loop are executed, but the SOP inside the loop are not. So, it is skipping the loop right? Or may be its just not executing anything in it

Comment: It gives the same result as Darhan's code. Gives output as: TABLE_CAT, TABLE_SCHEM, TABLE_NAME,....., IS_NULLABLE. I am looking to retrieving the column names.

Comment: you mean that `getColumnName` does not return the column name? How bizarre.

Comment: Yeah, it returns the column's description. Check [here] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) @ScaryWombat

Comment: In my code, it is using ResultSetMetaData not DatbaseMetaData. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName(int)

Comment: I totally get that. Even there it states it should get the column "name" and not the description. I even ran this code separately. Just connected to oracle and ran this code for the required table. Still it gives the column descriptions only.

Answer (score 0):

You have put OR condition .Which satifies everytiem and is true for SQL alone. Try to seperate while loop  and execute

```
 while(rsms.next()){
    if(rsms!=null){
            colNames[0][columns]=rsms.getString(4);
            System.out.println("colnames:" +colNames[0][columns]);
            columns++;}}
while(rsmo.next()){
    if(rsmo!=null){
        System.out.println(rsmo.getString(1));
        colNames[1][columno] = rsmo.getString(4);
        System.out.println("columno: "+colNames[1][columno]);
        columno++;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I have mentioned in my Question, I have tried it. And it skips anything inside the 2nd for loop, that is, the oracle one. Anything BEFORE or AFTER the 2nd while loop, gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

The operator '||' in your while loop works in the way that if first statement was true then he does not check any following statements. It is so called short-circuiting. Try to use single '|' sign or splitting in two separate while loops.

Comment: I have tried splitting too loops. Oracle one is skipped. Mentioned in the quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code for oracle

```
ResultSet rsmo = dmdo.getColumns(null, null, ORACLETABLENAME, null);
ResultSetMetaData md = rsmo.getMetaData();
for (int i=1; i<=md.getColumnCount(); i++)
{
 System.out.println(md.getColumnLabel(i));
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried it, it returns the column labels alright but i want the "Column Names".